# "Acabar com o problema" VS "acabar o problema"

Tags: significado, diferenças

*Acabar com o problema* ou *acabar o problema*? Qual está correto? Têm os mesmos significados?

Pelo o que eu percebi, *acabar com o problema* significa ’terminar o problema’.

Comment: Majid, eu editei as tuas perguntas usando o fundo amarelo para a frase-exemplo (que tens na outra pergunta); nesta pergunta, a frase que tinhas com fundo amarelo não é um exemplo, então tirei o fundo amarelo. Também usamos fundo amarelo para citações, mas não é esse o caso em qualquer das tuas perguntas. Naturalmente, as perguntas são tuas, e podes apresentá-las como quiseres (para mudar o que eu fiz, clica no "edit").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Acabar com qualquer coisa* é por-lhe termo, extingui-la; *acabar alguma coisa* é terminá-la, concluí-la.

A forma correta depende portanto do contexto. Se estou a resolver um problema de matemática, quando o terminar terei *acabado o problema*.

Se o problema é, por exemplo, um cano roto, ao resolver o problema terei *acabado **com** o problema*.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine o seguinte! Há um encanamento quebrado que vaza água constantemente. Para "terminar o problema" você tenta tampar o buraco, com as mãos ou de alguma outra forma. Porém para "acabar com o problema" você apenas tranca o registro. Então, "acabar com o problema" é ir até a fonte de origem do problema e dar um fim a ele. Já "terminar o problema" é como uma solução temporária, não impedindo que aquele problema volte a acontecer.

Comment: Concordo com tua interpretação de *acabar com o problema*, mas nunca ouvi ninguém dizer *terminar o problema* com o significado que tu lhe dás. A pergunta é sobre *acabar o problema*, não *terminar*, mas não me parece que isso faça diferença.